# Excel VBA store countifs for multiple or conditions

Tags: excel, vba, countif

I am using VBA Countifs to get the count of certain values according to the condition. Now I need either condition to count.

The below code work for count "No Video" rows and Non "No video" rows. But I want to count "No Video" or "No Data" as single output and another is without those two.

```
 Set R1 = appExcel.Range(cmdAudit2.Text & ":" & cmdAudit2.Text)
 Set R2 = appExcel.Range(cmbChoice.Text & ":" & cmbChoice.Text)

 NoVideos = appExcel.Application.CountIfs(R1, AuditType, R2, "No video")
 Videos = appExcel.Application.CountIfs(R1, AuditType, R2, "<>No video")
```

I found some examples which using multiple conditions "and" operator. But I want "or" condition.

For the time being I am using the below code to make it work

```
 NoVideos = appExcel.Application.CountIfs(R1, AuditType, R2, "No video")
 NoAudited = appExcel.Application.CountIfs(R1, AuditType, R2, "Not audited")
 Videos = appExcel.Application.CountIfs(R1, AuditType, R2, "<>No video")

 Videos = Val(Videos) - Val(NoAudited)
 NoVideos = Val(NoVideos) + Val(NoAudited)
```

Is there any good method which can be done in with single countifs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CountIfs doesn't allow the use of OR conditions like that.  You could add or subtract the Countifs in one line of code and avoid the intermediate step.  You could also use SumProduct, something like:

```
= application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(((R2="No Video")*(R2="Not Audited"))+(R1 = AuditType))
```

The above is air-code, you'll need to make the SumProduct work in Excel and record it to get the correct syntax.  For info on using SumProduct, see this [OzGrid page](http://www.ozgrid.com/News/apr-2005.htm)

Note that in the formula above multiplication creates an AND operation and addition creates and OR operation.